# How do I target players with only a certain X, Y, or Z coordinate?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to test for any player that is on Y level 118.

Here is the command I am using:

```
/testfor @a[y=118]
```

The problem is, the command isn't working as expected. In my chat when I type this command, it reads:

```
Found Boomcrasc078
```

The problem is, I am not on `y=118` when I run this command. What could be the problem?

I have also tested with a space:

```
/testfor @a [y=118]
```

but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use target selectors with `x`, `y`, and `z` alone. You need to provide some additional information to the target selector.

Here are some additional things you can provide.

- `r` and `rm`: Selects entities by distance. For example:

  ```
   /testfor @a[x=0,y=0,z=0,r=10,rm=5]
  ```

means that entities not more than 5 blocks away from (0,0,0) but not less than 3 blocks away will be selected.

- `dx`, `dy`, and `dz`: Selects targets in a rectangular volume.
  This one is more complicated, and it's too much to explain clearly in this answer. But you can find more about it in the Minecraft Wiki: [Commands][1]

The Minecraft Wiki also states about the `x`, `y`, and `z` arguments:

> `[x=<value>,y=<value>,z=<value>]`
> Define a position in the world the selector starts at, for use with the `distance` argument or the volume arguments, `dx`, `dy` and `dz`. Defining the position alone can be used with a target selector that selects the nearest entity from those coordinates, but it otherwise has no use, so applying it (and only it) to `@e` still selects all entities in the world.

This means that it won't be easy to select everyone on a certain Y level. You should instead use a different approach, by testing for everyone nearby a certain point in your world using the distance arguments, `r` and `rm`. If you still want to select everyone on Y level 118, you should consider learning how `dx`, `dy`, and `dz` work using the links above.
[1]: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selectors

Comment: For a simple plane in one direction (say fixed y coordinate), set the other two (dx, dz) to a large value (e.g. 10,000 blocks in two directions), x,z to a corner of the world, y the desired plane, then set dy to 1. This creates a 1 block thin slice of the world.

Comment: @aphid Actually, it should be `dy=0`.