# Teleporting players when a certain coordinate is reached

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to teleport all players who go to the Y level 8, but this command teleports all players from Y level 8 and the command block coordinates:

```
/execute if entity @a[y=8,distance=..10] run tp @s ~ ~100 ~
```

How do I make it so if someone goes to Y level 8 they teleport to safety?
I already know how to teleport players at specific coordinates, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I have not figured it out, but a short cut is putting a weird block below and when the block below them is that block, then they get teleported.
```execute at @a if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:grass_block run tp @p 273 20 -70 0 37 ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I target players with only a certain X, Y, or Z coordinate?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/370878/how-do-i-target-players-with-only-a-certain-x-y-or-z-coordinate)

Answer (score 3):

**Note: this answer is simply for teleporting the player up 100 blocks after they reach y=8. It does not necessarily teleport the player to safety.**

`/execute as @a at @s if entity @s[y=8,distance=..10] run tp @s ~ ~100 ~`.

You're close, but you need to use the `at` keyword to get the **player's** position rather than the command block's, and the `as` keyword to change the executor to the player.

The `if` then needs to be modified to use `@s` so it selects the correct person.

See [documentation on the 'as' and 'at' keywords](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute#as) on the Minecraft wiki.